# Calculate the minutes duration in android studio?

Tags: java, android, java-time

I have 2 `TextView`s, `timeStarted`, and `timeIn`. Both of their text values came from a database via `PHP` display like this:

> 11:18 AM

Now, I want to calculate their differences in minutes and display it to another `TextView` called `Differences`. After that, I want to make a condition where if time in is greater than 15 minutes to time started it will display a text "late" into another `TextView` called `status`.

Comment: Please share any example code you have already tried to help the community to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the times into `LocalTime` and then find the difference in terms of the desired unit (e.g. `ChronoUnit.MINUTES`)  using [`LocalTime#until`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#until-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-). Based on the value of the difference, you can make a decision.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.US);
        LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.parse("11:18 AM", dtf);
        LocalTime time2 = LocalTime.parse("11:45 AM", dtf);
        long minutes = Math.abs(time1.until(time2, ChronoUnit.MINUTES));

        if (minutes > 15) {
            System.out.println("Do this");
            // ...
        } else {
            System.out.println("Do that");
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Do this
```

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: thank you for replying but how do i apply your solution into android studio code? how do i display "do this" in an text view?